# Frenet Formulas for generic parametrization.

Tags: differential-geometry, curves

I know that this is the Frenet's system for Natural Parametrization:

> \begin{equation} {\begin{bmatrix}{e} _{1}'(s)\\\vdots \\{e} _{n}'(s)\\\end{bmatrix}}={\begin{bmatrix} 0&\chi _{1}(s)&0&\ldots&0\\
>  -\chi _{1}(s)&0 &\ddots &\ddots&\vdots\\ 0&\ddots &\ddots&\chi _{n-2}(s)&0\\ \vdots&\ddots&-\chi _{n-2}(s)&0&\chi_{n-1}(s)\\ 0&\ldots&0&-\chi_{n-1}(s)&0\\ \end{bmatrix}}{\begin{bmatrix}
>  {e}_{1}(s)\\\vdots \\{e} _{n}(s)\\\end{bmatrix}} \end{equation}

I tried to generalize that for every parametrization, is the following system right?? (so "s" is about natural parametrization and "t" is about a generic parametrization)

> \begin{equation} {\begin{bmatrix}{e} _{1}'(t)\\\vdots \\{e}
>  _{n}'(t)\\\end{bmatrix}}={\begin{bmatrix}a_{11}(t)&a_{12}(t)&\ldots&a_{1n}(t)\\
>  a_{21}(t)&a_{22}(t) &\ldots &a_{2n}(t)\\ \vdots&\vdots
>  &\ddots&\vdots\\ a_{n1}(t)&a_{n2}(t)&\ldots&a_{nn}(t)\\ \end{bmatrix}}
>  {\begin{bmatrix}\mathbf {e} _{1}(t)\\\vdots
>  \\{e}_{n}(t)\\\end{bmatrix}} \end{equation}

Or maybe something simpler? Like this:

> \begin{equation}
> e_1'=a_{12}(t)e_2(t)\\
> e_2'=a_{21}(t)e_1(t)\\
> e_3'=a_{32}(t)e_2(t)+a_{34}e_4(t)\\
> ...\\\end{equation}

I don't care if in generic parametrization some $a_{ij}=0$ but just if the formula is the 2nd or the 3rd system.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE, Francesco. Consider replacing (analysis) with a more specific tag for the relevant branch of analysis. *(autocomment)*

Comment: What do you intend the $e_j(t)$ to mean? I would still have the same Frenet frame, just in terms of the $t$ parameter, and the matrix form would still be the same as the original. It's just that the chain rule enters with $ds/dt$ multiplying the various $\chi_j$.

Comment: The $e_j(t)$ mean the versor of the curve wrote with another parametrization, no? (even I am not sure) Just $e_j(t(s))$.

Comment: But so this is correct?